# Как изменить value ползунка при наведении мыши?

Tags: jquery, input, mouse-event, range

Задача состоит в том, чтобы обычный `input[type="range"]` изменял свои значения при наведении на него мышью.
Для этого использую событие `.mouseenter(function() {});` через jQuery.

*Прикрепляю имеющийся код:*

```js
$('input[type="range"]').mouseenter( function() { 
  alert('Value = ' + $(this).val()); 
});
```

```html
<input type="range" name="state" min="0" max="10" value="0" />
```

Почему этот код, выводит заоблачное количество в console.log при клике ?!

```js
var state = 0;  // нужен для сохранения значения
$('input[type="range"]').on('mouseenter mousemove', function(e) {
    $(this).val((e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / ($(this).outerWidth() / 10));
    console.clear(); console.log($(this).val());

    $(this).on('click', function() {
      state = $(this).val();
      console.log(state);
    });
});
```

Comment: кинь целый код который у тебя пока есть

Comment: @KobetsMatviy уточните - изменял или возвращал значение.

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович добавил фрагмент кода

Comment: @UModeL Конкретно изменять значение ползунка при наведении.
Весь замысел в том, что я с помощью input[type="range"] хочу реализовать выбор рейтинга звездочками. Где будет 10 значений.
И при изменении value будет выше или ниже рейтинг.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть будет так:

```js
var state = 0; // нужен для сохранения значения

/* На jQuery */

$('input[type="range"]').on('mouseenter mousemove', function(e) {
  $(this).val((e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / ($(this).outerWidth() / 10));
  console.clear(); console.log($(this).val(), state);
});
$('input[type="range"]').on('click', function() {
  state = $(this).val();
  console.clear(); console.log($(this).val(), state);
});

/* На JS

var oRange = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');

oRange.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  this.value = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / (this.offsetWidth / 10);
  console.clear(); console.log(this.value, state);
});
oRange.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  this.value = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / (this.offsetWidth / 10);
  console.clear(); console.log(this.value, state);;
});
oRange.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  state = this.value;
  console.clear(); console.log(this.value, state);;
});

*/
```

```css
input[name="state"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" name="state" min="0" max="10" value="0" />
```

Comment: Ну ты крутой)) Действительно качественный ответ.
Сейчас работаю над тем чтобы при клике запомнило значение.

Comment: буду благодарен за консультацию на счет кода который прикрепил выше!!

Comment: @KobetsMatviy во втором примере кода, Вы назначаете обработчик _click_ всё время, пока двигаете курсор над ползунком, ибо он внутри функции для _onmousemove_. После клика, всё назначенное срабатывает разом. Ну и консоль не забывайте очищать `console.clear()`